# Reading from text file not working, deleting only partially works

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with reading and deleting from a txt file. It will not read at all, and when I delete something on my list box, it only deletes the information from the program, not the text file itself.

The error I get is

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'index' of 'StreamReader.Read(char[], int,
>   int)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TripCostCalculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string dir = @"C:\C# 2015\Files\";
    private const string path = dir + "PayCheckCalculator.txt";
    decimal tax = .06m;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(dir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        StreamReader textIn =
         new StreamReader(
         new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

        textIn.Read(txtName.Text);
        textIn.Read(txtDph.Text);
        textIn.Read(txtHoursWorked.Text);
        textIn.Read(txtGrossIncome);
        textIn.Read(txtNetIncome.Text);

        textIn.Close();
    }
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txtName.Text;
        decimal dph;
        decimal grossIncome;
        decimal netIncome;

        if (!decimal.TryParse(txtDph.Text, out dph))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid dollar amount");
            return;
        }
        decimal hoursWorked;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(txtHoursWorked.Text, out hoursWorked))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid dollar amount");
            return;
        }
        grossIncome = dph * hoursWorked;
        txtGrossIncome.Text = grossIncome.ToString("c");
        netIncome = grossIncome - (grossIncome * tax);
        txtNetIncome.Text = netIncome.ToString("c");


    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < lstSalary.SelectedItems.Count; v++)
        {
            lstSalary.Items.Remove(lstSalary.SelectedItems[v]);
        }
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\C# 2015\Files\"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("PayCheckCalculator.txt");
        }

    }


    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lstSalary.Items.Add(txtName.Text);
        lstSalary.Items.Add(txtDph.Text);
        lstSalary.Items.Add(txtHoursWorked.Text);
        lstSalary.Items.Add(txtGrossIncome.Text);
        lstSalary.Items.Add(txtNetIncome.Text);

    }

    private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(
         new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));



        textOut.Write(txtName.Text + ",");
        textOut.Write(txtDph.Text + ",");
        textOut.Write(txtHoursWorked.Text + ",");
        textOut.Write(txtGrossIncome + ",");
        textOut.Write(txtNetIncome.Text + ",");

        textOut.Close();

        txtName.Clear();
        txtDph.Clear();
        txtHoursWorked.Clear();
        txtGrossIncome.Clear();
        txtNetIncome.Clear();

}


}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete you have to set file path correctly

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\C# 2015\Files\PayCheckCalculator.txt"))
   {
      System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\C# 2015\Files\PayCheckCalculator.txt");
   }
```

Comment: @ the up-voters: he missed an  `@`; care to correct the errors before voting

Comment: Also, there's no problem using spaces in the path, please remove that from the question since it's misleading (plus, you haven't solved the main error, which is he has a problem with reading)

Comment: its prefer to  check  the permissions access  before you write/read delete the files/directories   
Eg:maybe you can use System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(filename)

Comment: Update: that works fine, thank you! I figured out how to display the info on my list box, however, is there anyway to delete the specific info (name, income, etc) without actually deleting the text file itself?

Comment: then show me the structure of the text file, I will try